# Copying data from table1 to table2, with slightly different datatypes, names and additional column

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, sqlbulkcopy

Im running a task where i need to copy data from `table1` to `table2`. `table1` is generated from a very old application which has a tendency of creating unusual datatypes, such as decimal etc. (these are unnecessary).

So the structures are as described:

**table1:**

```
ordernumber - decimal(11,0)
var3 - varchar(4)
var4 - varchar(30)
var5 - int(50)
...
```

**table2:**

```
id int() <- PK, AI
order_number - int(xx)
var3 - varchar(x)
var4 - varchar(x)
var5 - int(x)
....
```

So as shown, theres an additional column, `id`, in table2 and `ordernumber` is modified to `order_number` along with the datatype which is changed from `decimal` to `int`. The `x` is defined as it is not relevant in this context.

Is there a *clean* way to copy the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `INSERT INTO...SELECT` statament. Try

```
INSERT INTO table2 (orderNumber,var3, var4, var5)
SELECT orderNumber,var3, var4, var5
FROM table1
```

Comment: So basically the `id` field will live its own life and increment? And i assume that the select with the variables will just follow the order of the columns?

Comment: @JavaCake yep since `ID` is auto-incremented and it follows the order of the columns.

Comment: Perfect, i will follow this approach. Thanks.